# subscribing to route change and on init

Tags: angular

I have a question on angular 7.
I have a view that load some data on init. But this view must reload data on route change. 
In the url I have an Id that is used to reload the same view, that's why the onInit trigger only once.

Basically what I've done is to call the backend on OnInit then subscribe to route change and duplicate the call to the backend.

What is the best practice in this case? I don't think that duplicate the code is the solution...

I cannot post my code because I have a lot of backend calls and the code would be very long.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry... I put the wrong tag....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you are right! To avoid duplicate code you can subscribe to parameters of route and make API call again:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
    this.id = params.get('id');
    this.makeYourAPICalls(this.id);
  });
}
```

As `route` is type of `Observable` then you will always be notified whenever your route is changed.